# Provide d3 to vue component in unit test

Tags: typescript, vue.js, unit-testing, d3.js, jestjs

I have a vue typesript component that calls `d3.zoomIdentity.translate(0, 0).scale(1)` . This results in a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'scale' of undefined`. I'm currently mocking d3 with `jest.mock('d3')`. Of course I could go ahead and mock the d3-functions like I do with the store:

```
jest.mock('@/store', () => {
  return {
    turningStore: {
      get maximumDrawingArea() {
        return {
          diameter: 15,
          length: 10,
        }
      },
    },
  }
})
```

The problem is the amount of functions I would have to simulate with this approach.

Any chance to mock the d3-functions without having to actually write a mock for each one? Maybe just use the real d3-library?

**Edit**:
I was thinking about doing some snapshot tests later on, but for them to work we would need the real d3, not a mocked one, because we actually draw the elements with d3, right? So maybe not mocking d3 would be in our best interest. As long as d3 doesn't introduce braking changes using the real d3 in our tests shouldn't affect them negatively.

Anything that would make creating unit tests involving d3 easier would be much appreciated. **Thank you!**

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you mocking `d3`?

Comment: @tony19 Because `d3` functionality gets called in the `mount()` hook of the component. So some form of `d3` is required for the component to run, be it mocked or otherwise.